# Numbers in namespace

Tags: .net, visual-studio, namespaces

I have a bunch of classes under these four different namespaces:

- a.b.c.x
- a.b.c.y
- a.b.c.z

Neither of the classes that contain a definition for "myEnum" are directly under namespace "a.b". I have "myEnum" defined in "a.b.c.x" and "a.b.c.z" but i get the following error:

The namespace 'a.b' already contains a definition for myEnum.

Why is this? And how can i fix it?

**EDIT:**

Well i fixed it. Apparently i cannot have numbers like this "a.b.202.x" in a namespace. that's what it was complaining about. anyone know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Apparently i cannot have numbers like
>   this "a.b.202.x" in a namespace.
>   that's what it was complaining about.
>   anyone know why?

The same reason that you can't declare `int 202;` - identifiers cannot begin with digits in C#.

**EDIT**:

Here's an attempt to explain your *specific* (strange) compiler error, by reproducing it.

The following code:

```
namespace a.b
{ 
   enum myEnum {}
}     

namespace a.b.202.x
{
   enum myEnum {}
}
```

fails with the curious (to me anyway) errors:

```
{ expected  
The namespace 'a.b' already contains a definition for 'myEnum'
```

I *speculate* that the reason for this is that the bad identifier makes the compiler treat the second namespace declaration as "malformed", *ignoring* the `.202.x`. If this is so, it follows that it should indeed appear to the compiler that the second `myEnum` type is in the namespace `a.b`, which of course would be a duplicate.

This is further supported by the fact that if you get rid of the first namespace (and the enum in it) completely and recompile, you will see that the fully qualified name of the second enum-type is inferred as `a.b.myEnum` (despite the failure to compile).

[image]

Comment: But why does that cause such a compiler error? I would have expected some kind of syntax error instead of a complaint that a type was defined twice.