# Basic website gets error CS1002: ; expected

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to create a website using Visual Studio 2015 with Bootstrap and HTML but so far, the code I have doesn't run and I get an error message.

[image]]

Iv'e also been following the instructions on this site: [HTMLGoodies.com](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/making-beautiful-style-together-visual-studio-and-bootstrap.html#fbid=EG0Af_EYZM5)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title>Time Entry</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Logo Book</h1>
        <p>Discover Artists and Shape Your Perfect Logo</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:blue;">
          Welcome to Logo Book where you can browse through potyfolios of your prefered artist and see what they have to offer.
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:palegoldenrod;">
          Looking for an easier way to get in touch with these artists and give specific details needed for your project?
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:coral;">
          Feel free to use our Q&A section to voice and submit your needs such as fonts and images!
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's probably because you can't start off identifiers, especially namespaces, with numbers (the 2 in WebSite1.2), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949731/numbers-in-namespace) for another case of misleading compiler error.

Comment: You were right Zong, I started a new website project with the simple name, Website 1 and now it runs normally. Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

I ran this exact code on my computer, and it ran just fine. How are you trying to run this code? The easiest way to test if the code works is to type it in .html file, and open it with your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine in .aspx page also. On creating new web application,  Global.asax page doesn't contains line numbers 2,3 and 4. To run the page just remove them and run it. It will definately run. If you want to use that line no 2 then please describe your purpose for writing that line in detail. So we can find the solution according to it.